# Netcat stops when in a detached session

Tags: linux, networking, netcat

I want to use netcat to dump a number of blocks of strings to a file.  I've been running this in my linux terminal and everything works very well until I try to detach my command line.  If I run my command as a detached session netcat stops after the first round of strings.

In short, this works:

```
nc localhost 3000 > test.txt
```

But this doesn't:

```
nc localhost 3000 > test.txt &
[1] 9040
max@starbuck ncats]$ 

[1]+  Stopped                 nc localhost 3000 > test.txt
```

I suppose this has to do with reaching the end of a send on the server side, but I don't know enough about netcat to tell it, "hey! stay awake until your connection drops"

Ideas?  Thanks!!!

Comment: My guess is that `nc` is trying to read from its controlling terminal and is getting `SIGTTIN` and stopping.  Does it work if you add `</dev/null` to the `nc` command line to tell it to not try to read from standard input?

Comment: Or if you run nc from a screen session?

Comment: adding `< /dev/null` just causes it to exit immediately.  Screen is a possibility, but doesn't explain why this happens.  I'll use screen if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

netcat wants to send its stdin across the socket and print out the response, so it expects to have them both connected and active. I don't know a good way of creating a command that waits forever, but you could try

```
sleep 86400000 | nc localhost 3000 > test.txt &
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you for the explanation, that makes a lot of sense.  It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of `nc` support the `-d` option (noteably the OpenBSD version), which prevents it from trying to read from stdin.

So the code would become:

```
nc localhost 3000 -d > test.txt &
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution